# Angular JS+Laravel -- echo Angular data in the URL::route facade

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I developing a Angular JS + Laravel Application.
In my page I fetching my users list and when clicking a row it redirect to edit user page.

here is my code.

**Blade Template**

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in staffArray">
   <td>##data.user_fname## ##data.user_lname##</td>
   <td>##data.user_mobile##</td>
   <td>##data.branch_location##</td>
   <td>##data.catagry_name##</td>
   <td>
     <span><a class="editThis" href="{{URL::route('editStaff',["##data.user_id##"])}}">edit</a></span>
     <span><a class="dltThis" href="">delete</a></span>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]
**Angular Controller**

```
app.controller('staffController',function($scope,$http){
  $http.get('getStaffApi').success(function (data,response){
    $scope.staffArray = data;
    console.log(data);
 })
});
```

Laravel Routes.

```
Route::get('staffs', array('as'=>'staffs','uses'=>'StaffController@staffView'));
Route::get('edit-staff-{id}', array('as'=>'editStaff','uses'=>'StaffController@editStaff'));
Route::get('getStaffApi', array('as'=>'get_staff','uses'=>'GetApiController@getStaffs'));
```

Now I can't get the value of id in my controller for make the edit operation like below.

```
public function editStaff($id)
{
    $arr = User::find($id);
    return $arr ;
}
```

showing in address bar like **http://localhost/onetouchcafe/dev/edit-staff-%23%23data.user_id%23%23**

How to solve this issue...???
How echo Angular data in the URL::route facade ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Angular interpolation issues with your code

```
<a href="{{URL::route('editStaff',["##data.user_id##"])}}">Bad Href</a>
```

This will build an href as exactly you see it in your browser as the `#` are being replaced with a url encoded entity. Angular will not know how to interpolate this with the id you want as it doesn't see `##` in the href.

I can't see a way using the Laravel `URL` facade to stop it url encoding so you may have to resort to typed routes or extending Laravel to allow un encoded parameters.

```
<a href="my/root/##data.user_id##">Link</a>
```

Alternatively, don't use the route facade and let angular handle the click within the controller. (as pointed out in comments, this is not a very good way to do this but I'm leaving it here for reference)

```
<a ng-click="click(data)">Link</a>
```

Comment: `ng-click` is not a good idea for links as crawlers and even things like middle clicks will not work.

Comment: I understand that, it's listed as an alternative for that reason.

Comment: hi Valguss, Have you tried this ?, I can't getting success output.

Comment: I just updated this, I had a good look through the URL facade and can't see a way to stop url encoding of the parameters on output. Doesn't look like using the facade is going to help you much.

Comment: <a ng-href="http://localhost/onetouchcafe/dev/edit-staff-%23%23data.user_id%23%23" class="editThis" href="http://localhost/onetouchcafe/dev/edit-staff-%23%23data.user_id%23%23">edit</a>

Comment: That's the laravel facade encoding the parameter. Not much you can do to get round that (see updated section in answer).

Comment: now its successfully gone like edit-staff-1, but cant access with controller in laravel,  showing error like **The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.**